# Bad Request - Request Too Long when trying to insert image in excel notes

Tags: microsoft-excel, pictures

I'm trying to insert images in Excel notes but I get a `Bad Request - Request Too Long` error BEFORE the `Insert Pictures` dialog appears :

[image: Bad Request - Request Too Long]

We have tried clearing the cache of internet browsers, clearing the cookies, repair Office365, and reinstall Office365.

We have also tried going to Excel >Account > Account Privacy > Manage Settings > Connected experiences and disable "Optional connected experiences".

But nothing worked.

EDIT0 : We'd like to able to choose the path to the picture file :

[image: Insert Pictures]

instead of the error window.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the image URL publicly available? If so, could you share the URL in your question?

Comment: Try File > Account > Manage Settings (under Account Privacy). Under All connected experiences, disable "Turn on optional connected experience" and restart Excel.

Comment: related? could be the workbook has legacy sharing features enabled? note the "unsupported tab" which references drawing tools and picture insertion ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#targetText=Shared%20Workbooks%20have%20limitations%2C%20and,or%20open%20an%20existing%20workbook. )

Comment: @FlexYourData What URL ? We didn't type any URL. Please take a look at my EDIT0.

Comment: @Yorik You wrote about `legacy sharing` : Is there a newer way to share the workbook ?

Comment: its right there in the first sentence of the link

Comment: @SebMa which of the three options in the 'Insert Pictures' dialog are you using? If you are using OneDrive or Bing Image Search, then the path to the file you select is also a URL. If you used "From a file", then it's a file path. Either way, please try saving the file in a new location so that the file path is (much) shorter.

Comment: @FlexYourData You asked `which of the three options in the 'Insert Pictures' dialog are you using?` , the problem is we cannot go that far because the `Insert Pictures` dialog does NOT even appear, instead we get a `Bad Request - Request Too Long` error. I guess my first sentence was a little confusing so I've just modified it hopping it will be less confusing.

Comment: @SebMa I see. Please try the following: 1) Connect to a VPN first. 2) Connect to a different network or a wifi hotspot from your phone - basically, don't use the same network. I suspect that a) the dialog is loading an online resource and b) there are limitations placed on *something* in your local network that is preventing the dialog from loading. The something might be URL length, access to a specific resource that Excel uses, or something else. If you test on another network and it works, then you can surmise that it's something to do with the network.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you're trying to insert a URL, a link to an image that is online. To avoid this, when copying an image from the web,

- Paste the image into an image editor, such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) or [MS Paint](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Microsoft-Paint-in-Windows).
- Copy the *image from the editor* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy to clipboard, in most cases).
- Paste the image into the document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>).

###### or

- Save the image as a file (JPEG, PNG, etc.).
- Paste the *file* into the document.

Comment: What URL ? We didn't type any URL. Please take a look at my EDIT0.

Comment: When one cuts and pastes a picture from a a browser, *the URL* is copied, not simply the *image*. After pasting into an image editor, or saving as a file, that item becomes just the image. Copying and pasting an image from a browser directly to a MS Office document only copies the reference.

Comment: We didn't copy nor paste a picture from any browser. We're just trying to have the window that lets us browse on the PC to add a local picture in into the cell's note

Comment: Then why state, "We have tried clearing the cache of internet browsers, clearing the cookies?" What was the point of doing that???

Comment: My collegue did that not me, I guess he read that on the internet :)

Answer (score 1):

A client raised this issue with me today, and I figured out how to work around the error.

If you change the Workbook View to Page Setup, the error message does not appear and the Insert Pictures dialog comes up. It is when you are in Normal view that the error occurs. I've filed a bug with Microsoft.

While you are in Page Setup view, you can save clicks by clicking in the header or footer area in the sheet, and the Header and Footer tab appears in the ribbon. On this tab is an Insert Picture button (well, the caption is Picture, but that's what it does).

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you need to do:

delete the webview2 folder from this %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef. This clears the cache from the edge webview2 control that office uses.